# Probability that given two randomly selected points the second lies within the circle defined by the first

Tags: probability, geometry, geometric-probability

I have a set of N number of points $P=(x,y)$ that are i.i.d uniformly distributed inside the unit circle $C_1$ with center (0,0), each point $P$ represents a point on the circumference of a circle $C_{r_p} = C_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ where $r_p$ is the radius of the circle that $P$ lies on. Two points are randomly selected from the set, $P_1$ and $P_2$, what is the probability that $P_2$ lies inside the circle $C_{r_1}$ defined by $P_1$.
I worked it out to be $\frac{1}{N}\frac{1}{N-1}\frac{1}{3}$ but i'm not this is correct.
My workings are:
$\Pr(P_1) = 1/N$

$\Pr(P_2) = 1/(N-1)$

For any given point $P$ the probability $Pr(P_2\in C_{r_p}) = A(C_{r_p})/A(C_1)$ where A is the area, and $r_p$ is the radius of the circle defined by $P$

Integrating this over all possible $r_p$'s gives $\frac{1}{A(C_1)}\int^1_0\pi r^2 dr = \frac{1}{\pi}\times\frac{1}{3}\pi = \frac{1}{3}$

Multiply this by the probability of picking the points gives $\frac{1}{N}\frac{1}{N-1}\frac{1}{3}$

Is this correct?

Comment: Are the points independent of each other? If yes, then no matter how large $N$ is, $P_1$ and $P_2$ are two points uniformly distributed inside the circle and independent of each other. The answer cannot depends on $N$. If they are not independent, then the given information is not enough to have any definite answer. At the least, you need to know the conditional distributions of $P_2, P_3, \ldots$ when $P_1$ is given.  BTW, what is the center of circle $C_{r_p}$.

Comment: the center of all circles is the origin (0,0) hence it is defined inside the unit circle. All the points are independent

Comment: If all points are independent, then $P_2$ lies inside the circle of $P_1$ if and only if $r_2 \le r_1$. Since we are dealing with a continuous probability distribution, the event $r_1 = r_2$ has probability $0$. By symmetry $P[ r_2 \le r_1 ] = P[ r_1 \le r_2 ]$ and they sum to $1$. So the desired probability is $\frac12$.

Comment: I feel like $P[r_2 \leq r_1] $is dependant on $r_1$ (see in my working), but of course i may be wrong. I.e takign the extremes if $r_1 = 0, P[r_2 \leq r_1] = 0$ whilst  if $r_1 = 1, P[r_2 \leq r_1] = 1$

Comment: $Pr[r_2 \le r_1 | r_1]$ of course dependents on $r_1$ but that is not what you have been asked to compute. You are asked to compute $Pr[r_2 \le r_1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments already contain most of what there is to say; I'll write it out as an answer and show why your integration yielded $\frac13$ instead of the correct value of $\frac12$.

First, the probabilities of picking these particular points don't enter into the result. You're not being asked about the probability of picking these points but about the probability that, once you've picked them, the first lies inside the circle defined by the other. As was pointed out in the comments, this has nothing to do with $N$; the entire construction of $2$ points being picked from $N$ points that are uniformly distributed is irrelevant and an unnecessary distraction; at the end of it you simply have two points that are uniformly distributed, and that's all you need to know.

In fact, you don't even need to know that; all you need to know is that they're identically and continuously distributed, since, as achille hui has pointed out the answer $\frac12$ is determined entirely by symmetry, and all you need for this symmetry to obtain is that the distributions are identical and that the radii are almost surely different (which is why the distribution should be continuous).

As to why your integration yielded $\frac13$ instead of $\frac12$: You calculated as if all radii were equally likely. They're not; more of the circle's area is at larger radii than at smaller radii. The density of points at $r$ is proportional to the circumference $2\pi r$ of the circle at $r$, so the probability that you're looking for is

$$
\frac1\pi\frac{\int_0^12\pi r\mathrm dr\pi r^2}{\int_0^12\pi r\mathrm dr}=\frac{\int_0^1r^3\mathrm dr}{\int_0^1r\mathrm dr}=\frac{\frac14}{\frac12}=\frac12\;.
$$

Comment: thank you! Re. the points of circumference makes the answer a lot clearer now.

Comment: I was just looking over this again, and in the integration proof a factor of $\pi$ disappears as you have $\frac{2\pi^2}{2\pi}$, so the integration $=\pi \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @SamPalmer: Ah, yes, sorry, I dropped the factor $\frac1{A(C_1)}=\frac1\pi$ for the normalization of the area that you had in your integration -- I added it now; the result is still $\frac12$ (as it must be from the symmetry argument).